# Search Functionality in Laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to search through my posts but clearly something is wrong since i am getting no results whether the query contains data present in my posts or not.

here is my blade file and search function

```
<h6 class="sidebar-title">Search</h6>
<form class="input-group" action="{{route('welcome-page')}}" method="GET">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-search"></i></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

search function

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $search = request()->query('search');

        if ($search){
                $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' .$search. '%')->paginate(1);
        }else
        {
            $posts =  Post::paginate(2);
        }
        return view('welcome')->with('categories', Category::all())
            ->with('tags', Tag::all())
            ->with('posts', Post::paginate(2));
    }
```

I was trying to search the get the correct results

Comment: You're not passing `$posts` into your welcome at all, you're generating another request. `->with('posts', Post::paginate(2))`

Comment: whats the correct way to do it?

Comment: `->with('posts', $posts)`